# How To Redirect aspx files that are "Not Found"

Tags: asp.net, linux, wordpress, rackspace

I recently migrated my site from a aspx site to wordpress. The wp site is now hosted on rackspace cloud.

When I go to index.aspx I get the following message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. etc.
```

Previous times I have done a migration like this I uploaded a file index.aspx with a redirection inside and that worked well, but now it doesn't seem to find the file at all.

Nor did a redirect from the htaccess, nor the redirection plugin. I just get that same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the index.aspx present in the root of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Cloud Sites supports the ability to serve both PHP and ASP content from the same "server". I suspect you have "Windows Technology" enabled on your account which is attempting to serve the index.aspx file and ignoring the .htaccess file. The following articles should help:

[Cloud Sites KB - How can I redirect from ASP/.NET to PHP?](http://cloudsites.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/How_can_I_redirect_from_ASP/.NET_to_PHP%3F)

[Cloud Sites KB - How do I enable a secondary technology?](http://cloudsites.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/How_do_I_enable_a_secondary_technology%3F#Enabling_IIS.2F.NET)

Answer (score 1):

Your server may not be configured to treat *.aspx as html files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I do that? What do I need to look for?